# Insert values from Database 1 into Database 2

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, powershell

Here is the powershell script to query Database 1 and store records in $sql_output

```
$SQL1 = "SELECT Computer_Name, IP_Address, OS, BIOS
FROM ...
WHERE ..."

$conn.Open()

$cmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($SQL1,$conn)

do{
    try{
        $rdr = $cmd.ExecuteReader()

        while ($rdr.read()){
            $sql_output += ,@($rdr.GetValue(0), $rdr.GetValue(1), $rdr.GetValue(2), $rdr.GetValue(3))

        }
        $transactionComplete = $true 

    }
    catch{
        $transactionComplete = $false
    }
}until ($transactionComplete)

$conn.Close()
```

I need to store all the records of $sql_output, and there are **thousands** of these records

How do I create an INSERT statement that will insert $sql_output into Database 2 (which is on a different server than Database 1)

I'm using SQL Server 2008

Comment: @DanBracuk I'm using MS SQL Server 2008

Comment: Are these on the same DB instance? or linked servers?  why not just use an `insert into`?

Comment: @paqogomez Database 1 and Database 2 are on two different servers

Comment: linking the servers and running an insert into would be very fast.  Much faster than even a select and bulk copy into